# After applying drawLayer(rotationZ = myRotation), the onClick stops working. Do you have a solution for making a tilted button?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

This is where I apply the rotation/tilt. "rotation" is an angle calculated previously.

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .clickable(onClick = {
            println("click")
        })
        .drawLayer(rotationZ = rotation)
    ) {
        Text("button")
    }
```